Import nested subfolder file in Flask
I am using Flask and use Heroku in production
Everything is working great on my laptop, but impossible to make it work when I push it to Heroku
Here is my directory hierarchy from the root directory :
__init__.py (empty)
app.py
Procfile
sub1/
----__init__.py (empty)
----sub2/
--------__init__.py (empty)
--------file.py

My app.py :
from sub1.sub2.file import Myclass
x = Myclass()

My sub1/sub2/file.py file :
class Myclass():
    # Some code

My Procfile :
web: gunicorn app:app

Everything is working great on my laptop but as soon as i push it to Heroku I get the error :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub1.sub2.file'


I have tried relative import with from .sub1.sub2.file import Myclass but I get the error :
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I have also tried to :

import sub1 as sub1 inside app.py
x = sub1.sub2.file.Myclass() inside app.py
add from . import sub2 inside sub1/__init__.py
add from . import file inside sub1/sub2/__init__.py
but still not working

I have also tried to add the folders in the sys.path :
base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(base_dir)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(base_dir, 'sub1'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(base_dir, 'sub1', 'sub2'))
from sub1.sub2.file import Myclass

I have also tried :

from sub1 import sub2 in app.py
x = sub1.Myclass() in app.py
from .sub2 import file in sub1/__init__.py
from .file import Myclass in sub1/sub2/__init__.py
I get AttributeError: module 'sub1.sub2' has no attribute 'Myclass'


Once again, each solution works on my laptop when I do python app.py or foreman start -f Procfile but never works on Heroku... is it even possible ?

It turns out it was not a Python import issue.
On my production server I had a persistent storage set up. Instead of appending the files to the desired folder (sub2) during the deployment it was deleting everything and adding his own files...
I found this because when I unmounted the persistent storage, I saw a different issue popping up, that lead me step by step to this conclusion. So now the persistent storage is mounted on another subfolder to avoid this behavior.
